# Throw Custom Exception in JAX-RS

Tags: exception, jax-rs

I want to Throw custom exception but i Got error like :
`Error processing request. org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: com.daksa.restmockva.exception.InsufficientBalanceException: Insufficient Balance ........... blah-blah.... ​Caused by: com.daksa.restmockva.exception.InsufficientBalanceException: Insufficient Balance` 
Here is my TransferService.java :

```
public Transaction transfer(TransactionModel param) throws InsufficientBalanceException{
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setId(param.getId());
    transaction.setSrcAccountId(param.getSrcAccountId());
    transaction.setDstAccountId(param.getDstAccountId());
    transaction.setAmount(param.getAmount());
    transaction.setTransactionTimestamp(new Date());
    transaction.setTransactionDate(new Date());

    Account accountSrc = accountRepository.getAccountById(param.getSrcAccountId());
    Account accountDst = accountRepository.getAccountById(param.getDstAccountId());

    if (!accountSrc.getAllowNegativeBalance() && accountSrc.getBalance().compareTo(param.getAmount()) < 0) {
        throw new InsufficientBalanceException("Insufficient Balance");
    }
    

    accountSrc.setBalance(accountSrc.getBalance().subtract(param.getAmount()));
    accountDst.setBalance(accountDst.getBalance().add(param.getAmount()));

    entityManager.merge(accountSrc);
    entityManager.merge(accountDst);
    entityManager.persist(transaction);
    return transaction;
}
```

And here is my TransferResources.java :

```
@Transactional
@POST
@Path("transfer")
public Transaction doTransfer(TransactionModel param) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
    return transactionService.transfer(param);
}
```

Here is my InsufficientBalanceException.java :

```
public class InsufficientBalanceException extends Exception {
    public InsufficientBalanceException(String errorMessage) {
        super(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, that you need to implement [ExceptionMapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) for your *InsufficientBalanceException*